# Is $this->Session->read('Auth.User.field') secure in cakePHP 2.3?

Tags: php, cakephp

I've been working with cakePHP 2.3 for little while now and i've seen a lot of people using `$this->Session->read('Auth.User.id')`, especially in views. I'm however wondering how secure that is. Should you not create in the AppController something like

```
   function beforeRender() {

    if(!empty($this->Auth->user())) {
        $this->set('authUser',$this->Auth->user());
    }
   }
```

to check the user in your views? I can't find any clarification about this in the manual or elsewhere. Is Session secure enough to be counted on?

Comment: Depends on your definition of "_secure_". What exactly are you concerned about? ps. please always mention the exact CakePHP version!

Comment: @ndm 2.3, i just changed it :) Well actually that a user would be able to modify the session and change his `id` to someone else's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, depending on the type of authentication, [`AuthComponent::user()`](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.3.10/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/AuthComponent.php#L584) (it's a static method in Cake 2.x btw) reads the value from the session anyways (in case the static user cache is empty). So, in case the user would be able to modify the session value that holds the ID, both of these methods would be compromised.

Nonetheless you'd better pass the value to the view from the controller, the view doesn't know about the proper key as it's defined on the `Auth` component, also the `Auth` component implementation might change causing the view not to be able to access the value like this anymore at all.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, i'll use the `beforeRender` method then to pass the auth user to the view.